# react-redux props is not updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build a simple **todo-app** using `react-redux`. Problem is when I'm trying to update data, it would not update in view. My code is given below:

**actions**

```
export const listTodo = () => { type: actionTypes.LIST_TODO  }

export const updateTodo = ( payload, index ) => { type: actionTypes.UPDATE_TODO, payload, index }
```

**Reducers**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  all: [{
    name: 'init',
    status: false,
    lastUpdate: new Date().toISOString()
  }]
}

const listTodo = ( state, action ) =>  {...state, all: state.all }

const updateTodo = ( state, action ) => {
  const listTodo = {...state, all: state.all }; // init data

  // find data
  let todo = listTodo.all.filter( (todo, index) => index === action.index );
  // update data
  todo.name = action.payload.name;
  todo.status = action.payload.status;
  todo.lastUpdate = new Date().toISOString();

  listTodo.all[ action.index ] = todo;
  // return data
  return {
    ...state,
    all: listTodo.all
  }
}

export default ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch( action.type ) {
    case LIST_TODO:
      return listTodo( state, action );
    case UPDATE_TODO:
      return updateTodo( state, action );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In below code (`Components/list.js`), I just fetch all **todo-list**, and then print all list using `ShowList`.

**Components/list.js**

```
import ShowList from '../container/showList';

class TodoList extends Component {
   renderTodoList() {
     return this.props.all.map( (todo, index) => {
        return (
          <ShowList key={index} index={index} todo={todo} />
        );
      });
   }

  render() {
    return <ul> { this.renderTodoList() } </ul>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => { all: state.todo.all };

export default connect( mapStateToProps ) ( TodoList );
```

In below code (`container/showList.js`), todo list is shown using `<li />` and also have a `checkbox`, when user click on checkbox, `handleCheckbox` will trigger, and will update todo-list. I believe data is updated correctly, but it is not updated on `html`. In browser, todo-list remain same as before.

**container/showList.js**

```
class ShowList extends Component {

  handleCheckbox = (  ) => {
    const { todo, index } = this.props;
    todo.status = !todo.status;
    todo.lastUpdate = new Date().toISOString();
    this.props.onUpdateTodo( todo, index );
  }

  render() {
    const { todo, index } = this.props;
    return (
      <li> <input type="checkbox" onChange={ this.handleCheckbox } checked={todo.status} /> {todo.name} # {todo.status.toString()} # { todo.lastUpdate } </li>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => onUpdateTodo: ( todo, index ) => dispatch( actions.updateTodo( todo, index ) )

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ShowList);
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi sabbir, just wrote you an answer! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: check your store structure vs `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was in your reducers file. Whenever you executed `updateToDo()` you were not actually updating the the existing todos, you would just add a new property to your state with the new changes. This created layers and layers of properties without actually updating the first-layer. And since your components were only connected to the first-layer, it would never get the updated state.

I've updated a codesandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-flower-mwh79

You can update your reducers to something like this and then your code works completely fine:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LIST_TODO":
      return listTodo(state, action);
    case "UPDATE_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        all: state.all.map((todo, index) => {
          if (index == action.index) {
            return {
              ...todo,
              status: todo.status,
              lastUpdate: new Date().toISOString()
            };
          } else {
            return todo;
          }
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that solves it for you friend.

Comment: Why you are also passing `todo` in `this.props.onUpdateTodo( todo, index );`? if you are not using it and again in reducer doing same thing?

Comment: Whether `redux Action` takes `3` params as you are using in your sandbox code - `return { type: "UPDATE_TODO", payload, index };`?

Comment: @ravibagul91. I was trying to keep sabbir's code as close as possible. Really, I only needed to updated the reducer.  OP already had most of the setup, I didn't want to cause any confusion beyond that by changing other code, because the error was ultimately just in reducer.  Also, I don't think the redux action has a limit  on number of parameters you can set. I've looked at many documentation and nothing specifically says you have a max of 2. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line,

```
export const updateTodo = ( payload, index ) => { type: actionTypes.UPDATE_TODO, payload, index }
```

`Redux Action` will only take `2` parameters, `type` and `payload` respectively.

Here you are passing `3` parameters which is wrong. Remove your `index` parameter, then your action becomes like this,

```
export const updateTodo = ( payload, index ) => { type: actionTypes.UPDATE_TODO, payload } //payload = your updated todo list
```

Pass only update todo list to your action,

```
this.props.onUpdateTodo( todo );
```

Finally in your `reducer` only do this,

```
return Object.assign(state,action.todo) // This will merge your old state with updated todo list and eventually you will get a updated list.
```

See more obout `Object.assign` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: I have updated my code as you said, but still not working

Comment: can you make `console.log` in reducer function with `action` and see if your call actually going to reducer.